# How can I add a function to a appended html string in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, append

I am new to jQuery as well as Web development. :-)

I want to create a questions creation page. It has a Question Text Box and a Add Button.
When users press the add button, there will be a new Question Text Box and a new Add Button appear in the next line. But the old Add Button will become a Delete Button and change its functionality.

Here is jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
        $(".buttonMinus").hide();

        $(".buttonPlus").click(function (event) {
        $(this).remove(".buttonPlus");
        $(".buttonMinus").show();
        $("#p1").append("<p id='p2'>Question: <input type='text'><button type='button' class='buttonPlus'></button></p>");   **//  Here !!!!**
        alert("Welcome " + $(".ttt").val() + "!");        
    });

    $(".buttonMinus").click(function (event) {
        alert("You have pressed the DELETE button!");
    });
```

});

And here is the html code:

```
<body>
<div class="demo">
    <p id="p1">Your name: <input type="text" class="ttt"/>
    <button class="buttonPlus" type="button"></button>
    <button class="buttonMinus" type="button"></button></p>
    <br />
</div>      
</body>
```

I put all the Add Buttons and Minus Buttons into two different classes, ".buttonPlus" and ".buttonMinus".
The .buttonPlus works well when the line is added by the main html. But it fails to work when it is added by the .append() function. It simply adds the .buttonPlus's CSS code to its button, but the  $(".buttonPlus").click(function (event) {...} is NOT attached to the new buttonPlus.

Could you guys tell me why and how I can solve this problem?

Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to jQuery! This is a common issue. The problem is caused by the fact that the new `.buttonPlus` element does not exist at the time when you first bind the `click` event to `.buttonPlus`. That first time you bind the `click` event, it will only bind to elements that already exist on the page. This is the entire reason why you wrap all your code inside `$(function())` -- it ensures that it does not run until all the DOM elements have been created.

There are a few different solutions. The simplest one is to use jQuery's `.live()` method, as Ryan suggests. This will automatically bind the specified `click` event to any new `.buttonPlus` elements that get created.

However, while this is the simplest solution, it's also very computationally expensive. I won't get into the details here, but using `.live()` is pretty much never the best option. There is a similar jQuery method called `.delegate()` which can be used instead. However, while `.delegate()` is less expensive than `.live()`, it's still not the best solution in your case.

The best solution, as Diodeus alludes to, is to "re-bind these elements when they're added." You could do that in the following way:

```
function btnClickEvent(btn){
    btn.remove(".buttonPlus");
    $(".buttonMinus").show();
    $("#p1").append("<p id='p2'>Question: <input type='text'><button type='button' class='buttonPlus'></button></p>");
    alert("Welcome " + $(".ttt").val() + "!");

    //Re-binding
    var newBtn = $("#p1").find('.buttonPlus:last');
    newBtn.click(function(){
        btnClickEvent(newBtn);
    });
}

$(function(){
    $(".buttonMinus").hide();

    $(".buttonPlus").click(function(){
        btnClickEvent($(this));
    });

    $(".buttonMinus").click(function (event) {
        alert("You have pressed the DELETE button!");
    });
}
```

As you can see, all we're doing is putting the code that runs on the `click` event into a separate function. That allows us to easily bind it to the new button. You would probably want to do a similar thing with your minus buttons as well.

Comment: Excellent answer! Giving me a big picture of jQuery! Thank you!

Comment: Once you start using AJAX this kind of thing can become especially important.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a modified, but working version of what you've got going on in your code...](http://jsfiddle.net/8qWCv/8/)

You'll likely want to use [jQuery's live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function like this...

```
$(".buttonPlus").live("click",function (event) {
    $(this).remove(".buttonPlus");
    $(".buttonMinus").show();
    $("#p1").append("<p id='p2'>Question: <input type='text'><button type='button' class='buttonPlus'></button></p>");   **//  Here !!!!**
    alert("Welcome " + $(".ttt").val() + "!");
});

$(".buttonMinus").live("click",function (event) {
    alert("You have pressed the DELETE button!");
});
```

What this does is applies the same event handling to elements not yet in the DOM as they are added.

Answer (score 0):

When  you create a click handler only the elements currently on the page get hooked up. Those added later do not.

You can either re-bind these elements when they're added, or use jQuery's `.live()` feature that will do that for you automatically.